# CSF LFD suspicious process under user apache

Tags: csf, errors, lfd

I think my server got DOS'ed via HTTP(port 80).

When I checked apache access log, it showed that specific IPs requested /GET/HTTP1.1 more than 150 times in a minute.

And I've been trying to limit connection per IP via CSF.

However after I installed and configured CSF, I keep getting so many notification emails like this:

```
Time:    Sun May 18 22:34:40 2014 +0700
PID:     11727 (Parent PID:1636)
Account: apache
Uptime:  73 seconds


Executable:

/usr/sbin/httpd


Command Line (often faked in exploits):

/usr/sbin/httpd


Network connections by the process (if any):

tcp6: 0.0.0.0:80 -> 0.0.0.0:0
tcp6: 0.0.0.0:443 -> 0.0.0.0:0
tcp: 127.0.0.1:57790 -> 127.0.0.1:11211


Files open by the process (if any):

/dev/null
/dev/null
/var/log/httpd/error_log
/dev/urandom
/var/log/virtualmin/xxx.com_error_log
/var/log/virtualmin/xxx.net_error_log
/var/log/virtualmin/xxx.com_error_log
/var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log
/var/log/httpd/access_log
/var/log/virtualmin/xxx.com_access_log
/var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log
/var/log/httpd/ssl_request_log
anon_inode:[eventpoll]
anon_inode:[eventpoll]
/dev/urandom
anon_inode:[eventpoll]


Memory maps by the process (if any):

7fb758000000-7fb758021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fb758021000-7fb75c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
......
7fb765fad000-7fb7669ad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fb79bcfd000-7fb79d2f2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

as I stated above, I only want to limit the connection so I only modified the CT_LIMIT and incoming/outgoing ports in csf.conf

I know adding the execution path on csf.pignore might fix the problem, but that will also defeat the purpose of installing CSF in the first place.

My server specs :

```
Centos 6.3 64-bit
RAM 6 GB
4 Cores
Memcached Installed on port 11211
Apache with Prefork MPM:
  StartServers       8
  MinSpareServers    8
  MaxSpareServers   16
  ServerLimit      100
  MaxClients       100
  MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
  Timeout 60
  KeepAlive On
  MaxKeepAliveRequests 1000
  KeepAliveTimeout 2

MySQL
used only for hosting a wordpress
```

I dont know what happened here. Could somebody enlighten me?

Comment: lfd monitors processes by binary. If your /usr/sbin/httpd is not writable by anyone other than root, you can pretty safely add it to csf.pignore. lfd is not going to catch breakage within the httpd process anyway.